# individual user login time with concurrent users loadtest in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a thread group with single login request.
how can I observe the each individual user login time when perform loadtest with concurrent users(10)

Comment: Each request save its own load time, what didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as request label prefix or postfix like:

```
My Request, thread: ${__threadNum}
```

This way the number of current JMeter thread (virtual user) will be appended to the sampler name so you will be able to distinguish requests timings for the different virtual users when building your test report.

If your load test assumes > 1 iterations you can also consider [__iterationNum() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) to track current loop number, something like:

[image: JMeter Functions User and Iteration Number]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.